# Angular2 templating in ngFor {{ }} doesn't write to page / view

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

my Component creates a custom object array with a type I have defined elsewhere in my app like so

```
export class UserSchool {

    constructor (
        public schoolId: number,
        public yearRange: string,
        public schoolName: string
    ) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
        this.yearRange = yearRange;
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }
}
```

Now in my component I run the onInit method, speak to a REST service and push to my object array, like so...

```
// imports are here and correct... didn't want to add here incase too long
@Component({
    selector: 'profile',
    template: require('app/components/profile/profile.html')
})
export class Profile implements OnInit { 
        userPhotos: any;
        userInfo: any;
        gapageName: string;
        albums: string[];
        userData: any;
        userSchools: UserSchool[];

        constructor(private userData:UserData) {
            this.userSchools = [];
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            Observable.forkJoin([
                this.userData.getUserPhotos('123456'),
                this.userData.getUserInfo()]).subscribe(t=> {
                this.userPhotos = t[0];
                this.userInfo = t[1];
                this.gapageName = this.userPhotos.gapageName;
                this.userInfo.data[0].items[0].entries.forEach( (a) => {
                    this.userSchools.push(a); // this populated by two objects which I can log to the console!
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

All is cool and now in my template I wish to output my data in a `ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="#school of userSchools; #i = index">
    {{i}} - {{ school.yearRange }}, {{ school.schoolName }}
</div>
```

The index is output there is nothing for the `{{ school.yearRange }}, {{ school.schoolName }}`. Nothing is in the DOM either, when I should change on of there to `{{ school }}` the following is written to the DOM:  `[object Object]` I assumed that the items weren't JSON but when I write to the console the items are JS objects as it the `school`. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Try inspecting 'a' - is it really a school object?

Comment: When I write it to the console using `console.log(this.userSchools, typeof(this.userSchools))`; I get the following: `[Object, Object] "object"`

Comment: I'm more curious to see what 'a' is before you push it into the array.

Comment: When I do the same for a using `console.log(a, typeof(a));` I get the following in the JavaScript console `Object {id: 665, text: "1996 - 1997", title: "Silly School Winckelmann"} "object"
 Object {id: 664, text: "1994 - 1994", title: "Silly School BullyMan"} "object"`

Comment: interesting. I don't see a 'yearRange' or 'schoolName' property in your 'a' object. Try doing: {{i}} - {{ school.text }}, {{ school.title }} instead. I am thinking the object being returned from the async call isn't the school object you're expecting.

Comment: Ah! The data from the backend isn't named correctly!